# error with GetApplicationContext()

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create some classes in order to have a cleaner code but I've occurred in this error:
I have the following class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.metaio.sdk.MetaioDebug;
import com.metaio.tools.io.AssetsManager;



public class AssetsExtracter extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            AssetsManager.extractAllAssets(getApplicationContext(), true);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            MetaioDebug.printStackTrace(Log.ERROR, e);
            return false;
        }    
        return true;
    }    
}
```

In my main activity I call the AssetsExtracter class like this:

```
    // extract all the assets
    AssetsExtracter mTask = new AssetsExtracter();
    mTask.execute(0);
```

But I get an error on `GetApplicationContext()` on my AssetsExtracter class. It should be something related to the context but how should I edit the class in order to fix this?

Comment: You have to pass the context in your class otherwise it will not take any context using getapplicationcontext when you are extending the class using AsyncTask

Comment: Can you edit my code and show how it should be please?

Comment: check my answer i have added in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to be like this. Pass context in your constructor

```
 public class AssetsExtracter extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>{
 Context context;

public AssetsExtracter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
} 

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) 
{
    try 
    {
        AssetsManager.extractAllAssets(context, true);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        MetaioDebug.printStackTrace(Log.ERROR, e);
        return false;
    }    
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: ok I was almost there finding the solution :P Thanks I just needed to add this when creating the mTask,
 AssetsExtracter mTask = new AssetsExtracter(this);
Thanks everyone for the answer, now I understood better how this works :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to your `AssetsExtracter` class that takes a `Context` as a parameter, store it in a member variable and use the variable in `doInBackground()`.

Likely the async task used to be a non-static inner class in a class that defines `getApplicationContext()`, such as an `Activity`. As a self-standing class there's no outer class that would provide the method.

Answer (score 1):

You are extending `AsyncTask`.

`AsyncTask` does not make sense without an `Activity` or a `Service` to where she reports `onPostExecute()`.

So, make your class constructor accept your Activity's Context and then use `Context.getApplicationContext()`

Alternatively if you just need some async execution with no relation to Android UI you can use plain Java `Executor.execute()`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AssetsExtracter extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>
{

    private Context context;
    public void AssetsExtracter(Context context){
         this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            AssetsManager.extractAllAssets(context, true);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            MetaioDebug.printStackTrace(Log.ERROR, e);
            return false;
        }    
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: you can only pass the getapplicationcontext in the class that are extending the Activity